# Wondering if I can combine some rewrite rules

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I put up this web config file a ways back and am now wondering if I can combine or reorder some rules to gain a small speed increase. Thanks for looking. Perhaps canonical rule and http to https?

```
        <rule name="Redirect Folder">
                   <match url="^news/archive/*"/>
                   <action type="Redirect" url="articles/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirectoldaspfiles" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)\.asp" />                  
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>             
            <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true"> 
                <match url="(.*?)/?home\.html$" ignoreCase="true" /> 
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
             </rule>            
            <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule> 
            <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)\.html" />                 
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{PATH_INFO}.html" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                </serverVariables>
            </rule>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the relationship between the CanonicalHostNameRule1 and Redirect to https? Does these www.example.com is your web application's host url? If this is your url, you combine these two rules to one.

Comment: Sure, the actual domain is example.com. The canonical is https://www.example.com. In looking for ways to enhance page load speed, the other day I looked at my web config file, and thought that if I changed the http to https in CanonicalHostNameRule1, I might be able to get rid of the redirect to https. But I wasn't totally sure which prompted me to post this question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: note: it should have read h t t p s : // www. example. com but the h t t p s didn't display